# Is it possible to have two password files in Apache2?

Tags: apache, apache2, basic-authentication

Can I have two AuthUserFile directives in an apache2/sites-enabled/000-default configuration file?

```
    <Location /repo/trac>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Trac"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passfile1
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passfile2
      Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

I want username/password for two types of users.

- DEV - can access SVN and Trac
- NOM - can only access Trac

I have two options: keep separate password files for Trac and Svn and include them separately, or have 2 password files in 1 I put DEV in other NOM and include only 1 for svn and include two under trac location.

Comment: Why do you want to put them in different files? There might be a better solution if you state your goal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should move everything into a single password file and then use groups to control access to particular resources.  You can create `/etc/apache2/groups` with contents along the lines of:

```
DEV: bob alice
NOM: norm fred bart
```

And then modify your configuration so it looks like this:

```
<Location /repo/trac>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Trac"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passfile
  AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/groups
  Require group DEV NOM
</Location>
```

This would allow members of the `DEV` and `NOM` groups to access this resource.

If you *really* want to use multiple password files, see the documentation for [mod_authn_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html), which has an example that does exactly this.

Comment: your point is, it's not possible to include two files like I did?

Comment: My point is that there if your goal is to allow different groups of people access to different resources, your best solution is to use the facility that was designed to do exactly this thing...but see my update.

Comment: group way is better, I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you **can** in fact have multiple passwords files. The trick is to use AuthnProviderAlias

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html

**In your global configuration** :

*(as stated by @RickyLevi, AuthnProviderAlias can't occur in vhosts)*

> ```
> <AuthnProviderAlias file file1>
>     AuthUserFile "/www/conf/passwords1"
> </AuthnProviderAlias>
>
> <AuthnProviderAlias file file2>   
>     AuthUserFile "/www/conf/passwords2"
> </AuthnProviderAlias>
> ```

**In your vhost :**

> ```
> <Directory "/var/web/pages/secure">
>     AuthBasicProvider file1 file2
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthName "Protected Area"
>     Require valid-user
> </Directory>
> ```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider

> Providers are queried in order until a provider finds a match for the requested username, at which point this sole provider will attempt to check the password. A failure to verify the password does not result in control being passed on to subsequent providers.

Comment: mmm `<AuthnProviderAlias> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section` i guess this answer might work when `file1` and `file2' do act as a "provider" ? like `sitename-dev` as they will be turned on globally for all sites on the servers ?...

Comment: It's possible that you have to define global provider aliases, then use the one you want in your virtual host. In other words, define "global", "site1", "site2", ... providers in global conf, then use "AuthBasicProvider global site1" in your fist vhost, "AuthBasicProvider global site2" in your second, etc.
I'll try to get some time to test that.