# .htaccess AuthUserFile variable based on environment

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, acquia

I'm trying to load the .htpasswd file based on environment. If I hard code the URL it works fine.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/sitename.dev/docroot/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Our hosting provider is [providing](https://docs.acquia.com/article/introduction-htaccess-rewrite-rules) a global variable you can use in htaccess.

> `%{ENV:AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT}`  The Acquia hosting environment — possible values are `dev`, `test`, or `prod`

Using the variable we can check on which environment we currently are. If needed it can also be checked with the following rule: `SetEnvIf Host ^dev\. DEV` but I would like to prevent that.

I wanted to use an IfDefine but ifdefine doesn't read global variables. Is it possible to do one of the following?

1. Make the path a variable and store the path with the `AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT` variable and then do something like this: `AuthUserFile MyConfiguredPathVar`
2. Put a var in the AuthUserFile directly to concat like so `AuthUserFile /var/www/html/sitename.%{ENV:AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT}/docroot/.htpasswd`
3. Any other way to use ifdefine and check if `AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT = dev`

**Apache version 2.2.22**

**UPDATE 1:** It's possible to check the env with `RewiteCond`

```
# Determine whether environment is production:
RewriteCond %{ENV:AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT} !prod
```

Comment: [See if this Q&A helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540621/is-it-possible-to-have-two-password-files-in-apache2)

Comment: Also this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/68868/how-do-accept-multiple-authentication-options-in-apache though all these solutions require changes in server config. It is not possible from .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is auth modules don't have an access to ENV variables due to they are loaded before `mod_env` and `setenvif_module` modules. It means SetEnv and SetEnvIf directives don't work during auth processing and variables have not been set up yet.

You can check the order of loaded module by
`httpd -M`